# how to dispatch async functions using useDispatch in redux hooks

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get all users from firebase database and then set them in state but i'm getting empty `allUsers` in reducer/state. How to resolve this?

```
export const get_all_users = () => {
  var allUsers = [];
  database()
    .ref('/')
    .child('Users')
    .on('child_added', (data) => {
      // console.log('det all user', data.val());
      allUsers.push(data.val());
      // console.log('all user', allUsers);
    });
{* ----- getting empty allusers array here -----*}
  return {
    type: 'set_all_users',
    payload: {data: allUsers},
  };
};
```

Before `return` I'm getting empty value of `allUsers` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. From that you can get all users to a array called allUsers and then you can dispatch it.

```
export const get_all_users = () => {
    firebase.database()
        .ref('/')
        .child('Users')
        .on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
             const allUsers = [];
             snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                 allUsers.push(child.val());
             });
        });
};
```